# Fast check number to be a multiple of the big number

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a recursive algorithm that must be limited in time. If it takes too long, I am going to interrupt it. I check a time passed periodically as follows:

```
int g_counter = 0;
void myfunc()
{
    ++g_counter;
    if (g_counter % (1024 * 1024) == 0)
    {
        // measure time and interrupt if needed
    }
    ...
    myfunc(); // recursive call
    ...
}
```

Obviously, measurement slows down algorithm speed. Can this line:

```
if (g_counter % (1024 * 1024) == 0)
```

be optimized?

**Update**

I'm not stick to 1024*1024, any big number would be ok. I know that computer "likes" power-of-two-numbers. So maybe anyone can suggest something better that 1024*1024?

Comment: why not a simple g_counter == (1024 * 1024) ?

Comment: because I need to check it periodically, not once.

Comment: It should translate to about 3 machine instructions as is.

Comment: Have you *measured* how much it affects performance, or are you guessing? As others have pointed out, it's only a bunch of cheap instructions, and the branch should be highly predictable. Even a single function call might be more expensive.

Comment: `1024 * 1024 = 1048576` which means that if you allocate just 1 byte, when you'll get `true` out of this `if`, you will have a little bit over 1Mb allocated just for all those recursive calls, assuming that you allocate just 1 byte at each call. You are likely to consume all your stack-reserved-space ( tipically 8Mb under Linux ) before having problems with any time-related execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 1024*1024 is a power of two, you can do the same thing by `AND`ing with `1024*1024-1`, like this:

```
if (g_counter & (1024 * 1024 - 1) == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Note that `(1024 * 1024 - 1)` is a constant expression, so it will be computed at compile time.

However, any decent optimizer will do the same thing for you, so there is no point in complicating things: changing your current code to the above should not make a difference.

Instead of optimizing this code, see if you could remove it altogether: run your algorithm in a separate thread, and set a timer that would wake up your main thread after a certain time interval has passed. This way you would not need to check the timer at all - the system will do it for you, letting your algorithm run only the "payload" code.

Comment: ... so why did you post this answer? (BTW, gcc 4.7 indeed does this optimization at -O2.)

Comment: @delnan: It's a worth answer at least for me. I usually can not trust optimizations and like these kind of tricks -- As he noted decent compilers will do this optimization. How about coding for an old compiler on an embedded system !? and also +1

Comment: @delnan Because bitwise "AND" is generally faster than obtaining a remainder. Had it not been for the optimizer, the code from this answer would be a better choice.

Comment: @NM. Having worked with awful compilers for embedded platforms, I can assure you that peephole optimizations like this this are your least concern. It's not an advanced optimization (constant folding dates back to ancient times), and more importantly you can trivially verify whether it happens! There are cases where this optimization has to be done by hand (e.g. variable modulus), but this is not one of this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I know that. I even know why, down to the logical gates. But as you note, any decent compiler performs this optimization and doing by hand adds nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
int g_counter = 1024*1024;
```

...

```
if(--g_counter == 0) {
    g_counter = 1024*1024;
    // do your other checks
}
```